# Semi-colon as separator in jasperreport csv editions

Tags: csv, jasperserver

I want to makes my jasperrepport's csv documents values separated with semicolons instead of commas.

I've found net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.field.delimiter parameter which works if i adds it on my jrxml files :

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.field.delimiter" value=";"/>
```

But what I'm looking for is a global configuration file in my jasper server which can define this configuration key as the default for every csv repport.

Is their a solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set ***`fieldDelimiter`*** property in ***`applicationContext.xml`*** file (you can find it in jasperserver\WEB-INF\ folder) at JasperServer

```
<bean id="csvExportParameters" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.common.CsvExportParametersBean">
    <property name="fieldDelimiter" value=","/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I found this parameter but even when I restart the server it does not change anything. How can I force jasper to use this setting ?

Comment: Did you edit this file: apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml?  And set this property: <bean id="csvExportParameters" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.common.CsvExportParametersBean">
        <property name="fieldDelimiter" value=";"/>
    </bean>?

Comment: @Manuel Do you mean that exported data (csv file) has comma as delimiter instead of ";" symbol?

Comment: I do. And yes I have replaced "," by ";" in applicationContext.xml

Comment: @Manuel I've just set <property name="fieldDelimiter" value="$"/>, restart JasperServer and export report data as CVS. The result is: Sales person$$Account$$$$$Amount
Sarah Smith$$N & W Creek Transportation Corp$$$$$600,00  For comma separator I had: Sales person,,Account,,,,,Amount
Sarah Smith,,N & W Creek Transportation Corp,,,,,"600,00"

Comment: Do you have local instance of JasperServer?

Answer (score 0):

**JRCsvExporter works** but the above code gave me an error. The following code solved the issue for me...

**ADD CHARACTER_ENCODING before you declare the FIELD_DELIMITER**. Code sample as follow ([follow_up Link](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRCsvExporter/setParameter) for more info):

```
exporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "cp1252");
exporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.FIELD_DELIMITER, ";");
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
JRCsvExporter csvExporter = new JRCsvExporter();
csvExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
csvExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
csvExporter.setParameter(JRCsvExporterParameter.FIELD_DELIMITER, ';');
csvExporter.exportReport();
```